# Angular: add ng-click inside directive

Tags: angularjs

In my directive i using `appendTo` and `ng-click` inside it:

```
$("<div>" + "<a href='' ng-click='addIt()' + user + "</a></div>").appendTo '.user-class'
```

And `ng-click` doesn't work. Should i use `$compile`? How to use it in that case?

Comment: YES, you need to compile it, angular directives will bind to scope properties :)

Comment: to me this code looks a lot like there is a cleaner angular solution to this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LionC this code is a part of directive that make dropdown menu from json. There is no option to move this to directive template, so need to find solution how to make 'ng-click' works here.

Comment: You should be able to move this to the template, there's nothing I'm looking at here that would suggest otherwise. What parts can't be moved?

Comment: as @MathewBerg said, I do not see why this should not be moveable to a template. Bind your data to the directives controller and use ng-repeat adn ng-click in your template.

Answer (score 2):

> this code is a part of directive that make dropdown menu from json. There is no option to move this to directive template, so need to find solution how to make 'ng-click' works here.

Like Matthew, I am most curious as to which part(s) cannot be moved out into an external template / internal template function. It doesn't make much sense to me to have to re `$compile` a directive *only* to add a `ng-click` handler.

The senseful way would be to add the `ng-click` directive to a template. Either an external one, or a function returning a string value in the directive definition object.

*Running `$compile` after the `link` step has finished is not a good idea performance wise, seeing as how it recompiles the entire DOM element your directive is attached to. Avoid doing so for as long as you possibly can.*

```
.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    template: function (/*element, attrs*/) {
      return '<div><a href="" ng-click="addIt(user)">{{::user}}</a></div>';
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.user = 'John';
    }
  };
});
```

---

This would result in the following DOM structure:

```
<div>
  <a href="" ng-click="addIt(user)">John</a>
</div>
```

**[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kacemifiva/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: I would avoid the link function (and therefore fiddling with the scope) and just use the scope property of the DDO or even better, the bindToController property together with controllerAs. Makes the code a lot more fitting with current standards and future proof for 2.0

Comment: Agreed. The link here is just to showcase what the result would be in the simplest form. Like you say, getting the value of `user` from an outside source would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need $compile , inject $compile in directive and you can do it like this :

```
 var link = $compile("<div>" + "<a href='' ng-click='addIt()'" + user + "</a></div>")(scope);
 link.appendto('.user-class');
```